# JSON deserialization of variable named parameter using DataContract

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

Assuming we have a JSON object similar to:

```
{
  '12345': 'text string',
  'rel': 'myResource'
}
```

Constructing a DataContract to map to this type seems fairly simple such as:

```
[DataContract]
MyResource
{
  [DataMember(Name = "12345")]
  public string SpecialValue { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "rel")]
  public string Rel { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem arrives that the name of the property is variable so it not guaranteed to be '12345'.  Since this variable cannot be properly mapped using attributes it won't get picked up when using DataContractJsonSerializer.

If I change the class to support IExtensibleDataObject, I can get the value portion but not the property name which is a problem.  I'm looking to maintain this value during deserialization/serialization in order to be able to send the information on a return request.  I'm not looking to change over to using Json.NET to solve this problem as I want to know if it is possible in some form without resorting to an external dependency.

Comment: You could deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of a strongly typed class.  Would that work?

Comment: You can deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, but in order to do that, you need to set [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat=true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is only available in .Net 4.5 or later.

Comment: A strongly typed class would be preferred.  I wonder if I might be able to make use of a [Data Contract Surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064(v=vs.110).aspx) having the surrogate class read it as a dictionary and set the other classes properties properly.

Comment: You're going to need at least one more field in your class, say `public string SpecialName { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little ugly, but it turns out you can use an [`IDataContractSurrogate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate(v=vs.100).aspx) to deserialize the class with the variably named property into a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then copy the values from the dictionary into your class.  Of course, you will need to add another property to your class to hold the name of the "special" property.

Here is an example surrogate that I was able to get working:

```
class MyDataContractSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(MyResource))
        {
            return typeof(Dictionary<string, object>);
        }
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>) && 
            targetType == typeof(MyResource))
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)obj;
            MyResource mr = new MyResource();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetInterestingProperties(typeof(MyResource)))
            {
                DataMemberAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();

                object value;
                if (dict.TryGetValue(att.Name, out value))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(mr, value);
                    dict.Remove(att.Name);
                }
            }

            // should only be one property left in the dictionary
            if (dict.Count > 0)
            {
                var kvp = dict.First();
                mr.SpecialName = kvp.Key;
                mr.SpecialValue = (string)kvp.Value;
            }
            return mr;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MyResource) && 
            targetType == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>))
        {
            MyResource mr = (MyResource)obj;
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict.Add(mr.SpecialName, mr.SpecialValue);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetInterestingProperties(typeof(MyResource)))
            {
                DataMemberAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();
                dict.Add(att.Name, prop.GetValue(mr));
            }
            return dict;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetInterestingProperties(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite &&
                       p.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>() != null);
    }

    // ------- The rest of these methods are not needed -------
    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the surrogate, you'll need to create an instance of `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` and pass it to the `DataContractJsonSerializer` with the following properties set.  Note that since we require the `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` setting, this solution will only work with .Net 4.5 or later.

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DataContractSurrogate = new MyDataContractSurrogate();
settings.KnownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Dictionary<string, object>) };
settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;
```

Note also that in your class you should NOT mark the "special" properties with a `[DataMember]` attribute, since they are handled specially in the surrogate.

```
[DataContract]
class MyResource
{
    // Don't mark these with [DataMember]
    public string SpecialName { get; set; }
    public string SpecialValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "rel")]
    public string Rel { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""12345"": ""text string"",
            ""rel"": ""myResource""
        }";

        var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.DataContractSurrogate = new MyDataContractSurrogate();
        settings.KnownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Dictionary<string, object>) };
        settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

        MyResource mr = Deserialize<MyResource>(json, settings);

        Console.WriteLine("Special name: " + mr.SpecialName);
        Console.WriteLine("Special value: " + mr.SpecialValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Rel: " + mr.Rel);
        Console.WriteLine();

        json = Serialize(mr, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = GetDefaultSerializerSettings();
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
            return (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }

    public static string Serialize(object obj, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (settings == null) settings = GetDefaultSerializerSettings();
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(), settings);
            ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Special name: 12345
Special value: text string
Rel: myResource

{"12345":"text string","rel":"myResource"}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking after I stumbled across the Dictionary<string,string> as suggested.  It's not elegant in any means, but it means I can maintain the class as I hoped, thanks!

Comment: @ShelbyZ Thanks for the edit-- you're right, that was a goof on my part.

Comment: I finally had a reason to test this out with some other code and was wondering why the dictionary values were not being removed.  Safe to say the logic worked as intended.