# Create DataContract Class in c# from Json having Dynamically generated keys

Tags: c#, json, memorystream, dynamics-crm-2016, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a sample json like this :

```
{"'1234xxxxxx'":[{"AttributeId":"1","AttributeName":"Brand","AttributeValue":""},{"AttributeId":"2","AttributeName":"Color","AttributeValue":"Red4"},{"AttributeId":"3","AttributeName":"Size","AttributeValue":"44"},{"AttributeId":"4","AttributeName":"Resolution","AttributeValue":"Full HD"}]}
```

I have created a sample DataContract class like this :

```
  [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public  class Rootobject
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public attr[] attrs { get; set; }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public  class attr
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public string AttributeId { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }

   }
```

Now , I want to access the attributes using DataContractJsonSerializer and memorystream, but the problem is that the key '1234xxxxxx' in my json is dynamically generated everytime. So how should I access the attributes in my c# code?

Comment: Is `DataContractJsonSerializer` a hard requirement for you? Cannot you use Json.NET?

Comment: You can string.replace than deserialize.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [JSON deserialization of variable named parameter using DataContract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024768/json-deserialization-of-variable-named-parameter-using-datacontract/33027529#33027529).  Or just serialize a a `Dictionary<string, List<attr>>` using `UseSimpleDIctionaryFormat` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559991/any-way-to-make-datacontractjsonserializer-serialize-dictionaries-properly/27223290#27223290).

Comment: @botond.botos yes it is a hard requirement.

Comment: @Haksu can you explain a bit more as I am new to this :)

Comment: @dbc I have tried that settings feature but I didn't work out. Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If `DataContractJsonSerializer` is not a hard requirement for you, you could use `Json.NET` to deserialize the object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, ICollection<attr>>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: I cannot use newtonsoft.json or system.web.helpers class :(

Answer (score 0):

Here data model.

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Attribute[] Attributes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attribute
    {
        public string AttributeId { get; set; }
        public string AttributeName { get; set; }
        public string AttributeValue { get; set; }
    }
```

here static method that finds and replaces DynamicAttributeName

```
public static string FixJsonDynamicProperty(string jsonString,char matchChar,string newParamName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(newParamName))
            {
                return jsonString;
            }


            var startIndex = jsonString.IndexOf(matchChar);

            var lastIndex = jsonString.IndexOf(matchChar, jsonString.IndexOf(matchChar) + 1);

            if (startIndex >= 0 && lastIndex > startIndex)
            {
                var dynamicParamName = jsonString.Substring(startIndex, lastIndex - startIndex + 1);

              return jsonString.Replace(dynamicParamName, newParamName);

            }

            return jsonString;
        }
```

and this how you use it

```
var jsonString ="{\"'1234xxxxxx'\":[{\"AttributeId\":\"1\",\"AttributeName\":\"Brand\",\"AttributeValue\":\"\"},{\"AttributeId\":\"2\",\"AttributeName\":\"Color\",\"AttributeValue\":\"Red4\"},{\"AttributeId\":\"3\",\"AttributeName\":\"Size\",\"AttributeValue\":\"44\"},{\"AttributeId\":\"4\",\"AttributeName\":\"Resolution\",\"AttributeValue\":\"Full HD\"}]}";

    var newJsonString = FixJsonDynamicProperty(jsonString,'\'',nameof(Rootobject.Attributes));

    Console.WriteLine(newJsonString);
```

you can deserialize newJsonStringwithout problem. New PropertyName matches in RootObject.Attributes  . Also FixJsonDynamicProperty can be simplified with RegExp .